# Imported module disappearing?

Tags: python, import

**EDIT**: This is Python 2.7.6 32-bit.

A module I just loaded and deleted now cannot be found on import. Wat?

I've been using a plugin system called `yapsy` recently, and it wasn't very suited to my application (a chat bot), so I decided to write my own.

Everything works for the most part, but I'm coming across an odd problem - if I load a module, unload it (and delete all references so it's not in sys.modules) and try to load it again, importlib is unable to find it.

The offending code is [on GitHub](https://github.com/UltrosBot/Ultros/blob/plugins/system/plugins/manager.py) but I'll paste the relevant stuff below as well.

```
def load_plugin(self, name):
    name = name.lower()

    if name not in self.info_objects:
        return PluginState.NotExists

    if name in self.objects:
        return PluginState.AlreadyLoaded

    info = self.info_objects[name]

    for dep in info.core.dependencies:
        dep = dep.lower()

        if dep not in self.objects:
            return PluginState.DependencyMissing

    # module = plugins.control
    module = "%s.%s" % (self.module, info.module)

    try:
        self.log.trace("Module: %s" % module)
        obj = None

        if module in sys.modules:
            # Always False

            self.log.trace("Module exists, reloading..")
            reload(sys.modules[module])
            module_obj = sys.modules[module]
        else:
            module_obj = importlib.import_module(module)

        self.log.trace("Module object: %s" % module_obj)

        for name_, clazz in inspect.getmembers(module_obj):
            self.log.trace("Member: %s" % name_)

            if inspect.isclass(clazz):
                self.log.trace("It's a class!")

                if clazz.__module__ == module:
                    self.log.trace("It's the right module!")

                    for parent in clazz.__bases__:
                        if parent == PluginObject:
                            self.log.trace("It's the right subclass!")
                            obj = clazz()

        if obj is None:
            self.log.error(
                "Unable to find plugin class for plugin: %s" % info.name
            )
            return PluginState.LoadError

        self.objects[name] = obj
    except ImportError:
        self.log.exception("Unable to import plugin: %s" % info.name)
        self.log.debug("Module: %s" % module)
        return PluginState.LoadError
    except Exception:
        self.log.exception("Error loading plugin: %s" % info.name)
        return PluginState.LoadError
    else:
        try:
            info.module = module
            info.core.module = module
            info.set_plugin_object(obj)

            obj.add_variables(info, self.factory_manager)
            obj.logger = getLogger(info.name)
            obj.setup()
        except Exception:
            self.log.exception("Error setting up plugin: %s" % info.name)
            return PluginState.LoadError
        else:
            self.objects[name] = obj
            return PluginState.Loaded

def unload_plugin(self, name):
    name = name.lower()

    if name not in self.objects:
        return PluginState.NotExists

    obj = self.objects[name]

    self.factory_manager.commands.unregister_commands_for_owner(obj)
    self.factory_manager.event_manager.remove_callbacks_for_plugin(obj)
    self.factory_manager.storage.release_files(obj)

    try:
        obj.deactivate()
    except Exception:
        self.log.exception("Error deactivating plugin: %s" % obj.info.name)

    del self.objects[name]
    return PluginState.Unloaded
```

And some example output when in use..

```
09 Sep 2014 - 09:29:39 |                  Commands |     INFO | irc-esper | <g:#Ultros-test> .pl load control
09 Sep 2014 - 09:29:39 |                 irc-esper |     INFO | -> *#Ultros-test* Loaded plugin: Control
09 Sep 2014 - 09:29:42 |                  Commands |     INFO | irc-esper | <g:#Ultros-test> .pl unload control
09 Sep 2014 - 09:29:42 |                 irc-esper |     INFO | -> *#Ultros-test* Unloaded plugin: Control
09 Sep 2014 - 09:29:43 |                  Commands |     INFO | irc-esper | <g:#Ultros-test> .pl load control
09 Sep 2014 - 09:29:43 |                   Plugins |    ERROR | Unable to import plugin: Control
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Ultros\Projects\Ultros\Ultros\system\plugins\manager.py", line 175, in load_plugin
    module_obj = importlib.import_module(module)
  File "Z:\Python\App\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named plugins.control
```

So, clearly, something odd is going on here. `plugins.control` obviously exists and loads up successfully the first time - It still exists after being unloaded and attempting to load again - so.. I really have no idea what's going on.

I can see that the module is losing all references - which is what I want - and so is being removed from sys.modules, but well, I really don't understand this behavior.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!

After a bit of messing around, I noticed that I'd overlooked that `info.module` was being set on each plugin load, being prefixes with `"plugins."` each time.

- -> `control`
- -> `plugins.control`
- -> `plugins.plugins.control`

Thus causing the ImportError.